# JAXB: Remove extra unneeded tag

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the following code:

```
public class TestElement {

  @XmlElement
  private Field field;

  private boolean isEmpty;
  ...

}

@XmlRootElement
public class MainTest {

  @XmlElement
  private TestElement el1

  @XmlElement
  private TestElement el2
  ...
}
```

After marshalling, this results in an XML-file with something like:

```
<MainTest>
  <TestElement id=el1>
    <Field>...</Field>
  </TestElement>   
  <TestElement id=el2>
    <Field>...</Field>
  </TestElement>    
</MainTest>
```

I would however like to remove the <Field> tags so the file shows up as

```
<MainTest>
  <TestElement id=el1>...</TestElement>   
  <TestElement id=el2>...</TestElement>    
</MainTest>
```

Is there any way to do this? The field `field` in the class `TestElement` is the only field that should be represent in the XML file.

(For clarification: I do not want to drop the value between `<Field>` and `</Field>`, I simple want to drop the unnecessary tags encapsulating the value.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RobertMoskal: I am not trying to exclude the field `Field`. I am simply trying to drop the XML-tag around it's value, since the tag itself is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for me. Instead of annotating the whole TestElement object, I have created a (private) getter in my `MainTest`class for each TestElement object. I have changed `MainTest`to:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MainTest {

  private TestElement el1

  private TestElement el2
  ...

  @XmlElement(name="TestElement")
  private Field getFieldEl1() {
    return el1.getField();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use @XmlValue on Field getter method